# Is it possible to design UI of a desktop apllication with HTML5 and CSS3 and coding it's event handling in pure java?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, desktop-application

i am a student i started studying swing 2 days ago and i was wondering if we could just design the the whole UI of a desktop application using HTML5 and CSS3 and instead of JavaScript if we could code in pure java for the application's event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, what you need is a way to embed a web browser into your swing application. With the latest version of Java you can use JavaFX have a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

There are other solution for older version like one from Eclipse:

http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/2.3/guide/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html

Hope this helps